# How can I improve readability and length of a method with many if statements?

Tags: java, if-statement, design-patterns

I have a method with 195 ifs. Here is a shorter version:

```
private BigDecimal calculateTax(String country, BigDecimal amount) throws Exception {
    if(country.equals("POLAND")){
        return new BigDecimal(0.23).multiply(amount);
    }
    else if(country.equals("AUSTRIA")) {
        return new BigDecimal(0.20).multiply(amount);
    }
    else if(country.equals("CYPRUS")) {
        return new BigDecimal(0.19).multiply(amount);
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("Country not supported");
    }
}
```

I can change ifs to switches:

```
private BigDecimal calculateTax(String country, BigDecimal amount) throws Exception {
    switch (country) {
        case "POLAND":
            return new BigDecimal(0.23).multiply(amount);
        case "AUSTRIA":
            return new BigDecimal(0.20).multiply(amount);
        case "CYPRUS":
            return new BigDecimal(0.19).multiply(amount);
        default:
            throw new Exception("Country not supported");
    }
}
```

but 195 cases is still so long. How could I improve readability and length of that method? What pattern would be the best in this case?

Comment: Use `java.util.Map` ... ?

Comment: Yeah, a map or a dictionary is probably your best bet here.

Comment: Good point guys, but can I also put a design pattern here? Let's say that I am forced to

Comment: You would probably be best off loading in a csv from disk, then storing it in a map.

Comment: Warning: avoid using float point numbers with BigDecimal. BigDecimal(0.23) might not be the same as BigDecimal(23)/BigDecimal(100). The latter is the correct representation of 23%.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about improving the readability of existing, working code belong on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @ncbvs You should definitely not use a map, it'll work for this toy problem, but it's really limited in future expandability (when you want more cases, more payloads in addition to the tax rate, etc.). This is what object orientation is for. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592485/3141234).

Comment: Bigger question: how do you intend to keep those values 'fresh'

Comment: Get rid of the apostrophe please. It's "ifs" and not "if's".

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Create a `Map<String,Double>` that maps country names to their corresponding tax rates:

```
Map<String,Double> taxRates = new HashMap<> ();
taxRates.put("POLAND",0.23);
...
```

Use that `Map` as follows:

```
private BigDecimal calculateTax(String country, BigDecimal amount) throws Exception {
    if (taxRates.containsKey(country)) {
        return new BigDecimal(taxRates.get(country)).multiply(amount);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Country not supported");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a reasonable place to throw a checked exception. I know that OP's code does this, but I'd still rather not propagate it.

Comment: @BenP. I see no issue with throwing a checked exception if you receive an unexpected/not supported input. I'd probably use some custom exception and not the base Exception class though.

Comment: Or alternatively    `Optional.ofNullable(taxRateMap.get(country))
            .mapping(taxRate -> new BigDecimal(taxRate).multiply(amount);
            .orElseThrow( () ->  new Exception("Country " + country + " not supported"));`

Comment: An `IllegalArgumentException` should be fine, but a plain `Exception` is a no-go...

Comment: You should definitely not use a map, it'll work for this toy problem, but it's really limited in future expandability (when you want more cases, more payloads in addition to the tax rate, etc.). This is what object orientation is for. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592485/3141234).

Comment: Small nitpick: `Map.ofEntries()` is probably nicer than repeating all the `put` calls. Larger nitpick: That's still too much code duplication, and some of the other commenters are right, IMHO, to factor the data out into a file or database and populate the map from it or query the data source directly. Medium nit: yeah, what others said about exceptions. :)

Comment: @davidxxx i would suggest just returning the optional. Returning a value or maybe not is what optionals are for

Comment: isn't refusing to use a Map "because it might become more complicated later" an example where YAGNI applies?

Comment: @Alexander There's no "_You should **definitely** not use a map_" here. There are 2 different optimizations: Development speed on one hand, on the other hand preparing for something that _maybe might_ happen in the future. Which is a prime example for [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), really. Following your logic, you would almost never simply use a map, because almost always _maybe_ in the future you _might_ want to add stuff.

Comment: @RaphaelSchmitz Fair point, but tax policy is one domain that's particularly complex and ever changing. I can't think of a worse domain to make simplistic assumptions (all taxes are flat rate, tax rates don't change, tax rates are uniform throughout an entire country, etc. etc. etc.). Any non-toy version of this code has to contend with these complexities, or it would just be broken.

Comment: @Alexander It does come down to what it's being used for. It might be for a specialised webshop for one type of product - T-shirts, big machinery etc, this isn't so rare that I would call it an edge case. However, I do agree that it's a complex subject matter where people tend make assumptions that are too simple, just like with [addresses](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/).

Comment: @RaphaelSchmitz Haven't seen that post, thanks for sharing! A saw a [similar one for names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/), and it's great . Recently I've also been seeing a lot of people implementing their own phone number pretty-printing/formating/parsing functionality, and I'm like "oh my sweet summer child, you have no idea [how complicated that is](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md)"

Comment: this works for simple systems, I also advise moving the country:rate info into a file to avoid having to update the code on changes.
But, the if you have more complex tax logic then @Alexander 's response is the correct, which is truly expandable.

Answer (score 24):

Put the data in an XML file or database, then use it to populate a dictionary. That way you can change the data easily, and separate the data from your application logic. Or, just execute a SQL query in your method instead.

Answer (score 14):

***Don't do this!***

As it is right now, your `calculateTax` method is like a container for four actual `calculateTax` methods, one for each of the 3 countries, and one for the invalid case. Every other method you make along these lines will be like that. Following this pattern, you'll end up with many switches (checking for the same set of cases) within many methods, where each case contains the specifics of a case. But that's exactly polymorphism does, in a much better way!

Patterns like this are a very strong indication that you're not taking advantage of object orientation, and barring any other reasons not to, you definitely should. It's Java after all, and that's kind of the whole schtick.

Create an interface like `TaxPolicy`:

```
interface TaxPolicy {
    BigDecimal calculateTaxFor(BigDecimal saleAmount);
}
```

Create a class that implements it:

```
class NationalSalesTaxPolicy implements TaxPolicy  {
    String countryName;
    BigDecimal salesTaxRate;

    // Insert constructor, getters, setters, etc. here

    BigDecimal calculateTaxFor(BigDecimal saleAmount) {
        return saleAmount.multiply(salesTaxRate);         
    }
}
```

Then, create objects of this class, one per country you wish to support. We can wrap this list into a new class, `NationalSalesTaxCalculator`, which will be our one-stop-shop for calculating sales tax for any country:

```
class NationalSalesTaxCalculator {
    static Map<String, NationalSalesTaxPolicy> SUPPORTED_COUNTRIES = Stream.of(
        new NationalSalesTaxPolicy("POLAND", "0.23"),
        new NationalSalesTaxPolicy("AUSTRIA", "0.20"),
        new NationalSalesTaxPolicy("CYPRUS", "0.19")
    ).collect(Collectors.toMap(NationalSalesTaxPolicy::getCountryName, c -> c));

    BigDecimal calculateTaxFor(String countryName, BigDecimal saleAmount) {
        NationalSalesTaxPolicy country = SUPPORTED_COUNTRIES.get(countryName);
        if (country == null) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Country not supported");

        return country.calculateTaxFor(saleAmount);
    }
}
```

And we can use it like:

```
NationalSalesTaxCalculator calculator = new NationalSalesTaxCalculator();
BigDecimal salesTax = calculator.calculateTaxFor("AUSTRIA", new BigDecimal("100"));
System.out.println(salesTax);
```

Some key benefits to notice:

1. If you add a new country you want to support, you just have to create a new object. All methods that might need that object, automatically "do the right thing", without needing to manually find them all, in order to add in new if statements.
2. You have room to adapt functionality as necessary. For example, where I live (Ontario, Canada), sales tax isn't charged for groceries. So I could make my own subclass of `NationalSalesTaxPolicy` that has more nuanced logic.
3. There's even some more room for improvement. Notice that `NationalSalesTaxCalculator.calculateTaxFor()` contains some code specific to handling an unsupported country. If we add in new operations to that class, every method would need the same null check and error throw.

   Instead, that could be refactored into using the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern). You implement an `UnsuppoertedTaxPolicy`, which is a class that
   implements all interface methods by throwing exceptions. Like so:

   ```
   class UnsuppoertedTaxPolicy implements TaxPolicy {
       public BigDecimal calculateTaxFor(BigDecimal saleAmount) {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Country not supported");
       }
   }
   ```

   You can then do

   ```
   TaxPolicy countryTaxPolicy = Optional
       .ofNullable(SUPPORTED_COUNTRIES.get(countryName))
       .orElse(UNSUPPORTED_COUNTRY);
   return countryTaxPolicy.calculateTaxFor(saleAmount);
   ```

   This "centralizes" all your exceptions into one place, which makes them easier to find (thus easier to set break points on), easier to edit (in case you ever want to migrate the exception types, or change the message), and it declutters the rest of the code, so that it only needs to worry about the happy case.

Here's a working demo: https://repl.it/@alexandermomchilov/Polymorphism-over-ifswitch

Comment: The thing is, this isn't really expandable anyway. To add functionality like "don't charge sales tax for groceries in Canada" (or worse, Ontario), you'll need to change the interface anyway. The problem in general calls for OOP, but the only thing you really have here is adding lots of code that doesn't really do anything. You're not saving any development time by changing the code to OO before you have a reason to do so. Of course, *as soon as there's such a requirement* (like your variable sales tax), this is the way to go. Until then, a simple method works better.

Comment: Don't do this either. You still need to hard-code many values which might change in a few months. Writing the data as JSON/Sqlite/XML would be a better choice.

Comment: Big nitpick: [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). Small nitpick: Putting (in spirit) "polymorphism is the solution" in the first part doesn't really fit. The "_you'll end up with many switches_" issue is solved with a `Map`, just like the accepted answer. Only in the end (as solution to a different problem!), you actually provide "a single interface to entities of different types" (`NationalSalesTaxPolicy` vs. `UnsupportedTaxPolicy`).

Comment: That's really [enterprise quality coding](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition). To some extent, I agree: As a rule of thumb, **every** `switch` and even most `if`s should at least be *considered* as a candidate to be implemented with polymorphy. But at this point, the interface is trivially `BigDecimal compute(String, BigDecimal)`. Even *if* those structures were in place, I'd pull out your usage example into a (private static) method with exactly this signature, where the `calculator` instance is created. Now you could start with dependency injection...

Comment: @Marco13 This is one of the places where I see it as most fitting. I'm not a fan of enterprise Java in general, but this domain is particularly fast-changing and warrants it, IMHO.

Comment: @EricDuminil The potential to enterprise it more has no end :')

Comment: @Luaan Migrating this interface is relatively easy, ("add an overloaded method to the interface that excepts some kind of `PurchaseProperties` object", and add a default implementation that disregards it and forwards to the existing method). "You're not saving any development time by changing the code to OO before you have a reason to do so" I disagree. I've seen to many massively copy/pasted `switch` constructions. Once people start on that route, they keep pushing down it because migrating to polymorphism would be such a pain, and it just gets worse and worse over time

Comment: @Luaan I wouldn't advocate doing this in all cases, but I would certainly advocate for it in a domain as complex and ever-changing as taxes.

Answer (score 10):

As a frame challenge...

195 cases is not too long ***if*** it's clear what they're doing and why, and ***if*** the code inside each case is minimal. Yes it's long, but it's perfectly readable because you know exactly what it's doing. Length does not necessarily imply unreadability.

As other answers have said of course, this may be a code smell indicating you're not using OO properly. But on its own, it's just long, not unreadable.

Comment: The only thing really smelling at all here is the repeated "amount * taxRate". Not only is it easily solved, but it would also make it hard to spot that one case which does something different (which will almost inevitably come at some point).

Comment: Actually the 195 is not the real problem. The real problem is, that these numbers are volatile, and change on specific dates (when tax rates changes). So there needs to be a consistent update method/process also allowing to put in future changes. Hard coding this, and changing by hand, probably with a personal calender notification is not a solution. (except for toy programms)

Comment: @Luann I'd think the one case where it's different would stand out more in the code? Of course *forgetting* to cover that one case from requirements would be all too easy! I agree with everyone else that the OP's specific example has better ways of solving the problem. In general though, I don't share the OP's concern about long functions if what they're doing is clear and hence they can readily be checked for correctness against design/requirements. That's really what matters, and recommendations for function length are just a way to help make that easier.

Answer (score 5):

If the values are constant and are not meant to be changed regularly (which I doubt). I'd introduce a static metamodel using Enum:

```
public enum CountryList {

    AUSTRIA(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.20)),
    CYPRUS(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.19)),
    POLAND(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.23));

    private final BigDecimal countryTax;

    CountryList(BigDecimal countryTax) {
        this.countryTax = countryTax;
    }

    public BigDecimal getCountryTax() {
        return countryTax;
    }

    public static BigDecimal countryTaxOf(String countryName) {
        CountryList country = Arrays.stream(CountryList.values())
                .filter(c -> c.name().equalsIgnoreCase(countryName))
                .findAny()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Country is not found in the dictionary: " + countryName));

        return country.getCountryTax();
    }
}
```

Then

```
private BigDecimal calculateTax(String country, BigDecimal amount) throws Exception {
    return CountryList.countryTaxOf(country).multiply(amount);
}
```

It's readable, compile time safe, easily extendable with additional metadata per country and less boilerplate.

Comment: Why the stream?

Comment: What's wrong about it? `stream()` usually faster than `for-loop` and there's no side effects.

Comment: “stream() usually faster than for-loop” — is there any evidence for that?  It's likely for parallel streams and very large numbers, but for a small number like 195 the overhead of set-up, heap churn, &c (and, if parallel, synchronisation) is likely to dwarf any potential saving.  There are good reasons for using streams, but performance on small numbers isn't one of them!

Comment: _is there any evidence for that?_ How about [benchmarking](https://gist.github.com/82aa0f0a58b2f059cb6bee1bf73e0697)? `forEachStream` seems to be 1.3 - 1.5 times faster than the same `for-loop`. I'm not even talking about conciseness/readability.

Comment: Well, I was also wondering why you didn't use `CountryList.valueOf(countryName.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT))` (make sure to specify locale when doing case insensitive comparisons!)

Comment: @immibis This is a nice suggestion. However someone might refactor the enum's value from `AUSTRIA` to `Austria`. The method likely remain unnoticed/unchanged and will stop working. I'd avoid hardcoding enum values case.

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov Likewise someone might rename CZECHREPUBLIC to CZECHIA even if you use equalsIgnoreCase. I'd add a comment saying the names are important and what to consider before changing them.

Answer (score 4):

*EDIT: missed @Alexander's answer; it might be a bit overkill, but he's hitting the main point as well: use OOP.*
*EDIT 2: implemented @Luaan's suggestions*

I'm probably missing something obvious, and it might be a bit hard to implement at this late a stage, but this looks to me like a perfect case for **Object Oriented Programming**:

You create a `Country` class which contains everything pertaining to a country, such as a `name` and a `calculateTax()` method and whatnot, and then your caller (`calculateTotalAmount()`, or whatever) will call `country.calculateTax(amount)` instead of `calculateTax(country, amount)`, and the entire if/switch construction is just gone.

Besides, when you add support for a new country (say, there's another civil war somewhere and a country splits up), you just add everything for the new country in one single place instead of hunting down a gazillion methods with gigantic `if()` chains or `switch()`es...

Comment: Having a public taxFactor isn't really "OOP", you're basically reinventing procedural/early functional programming (not that there's anything wrong with that). A more OOP approach would be either having the tax calculation in the country object, or having a separate tax calculator object that can be created for a given country (and potentially accept other arguments). This gets especially important when you realize that countries often don't have unified tax rates in the first place.

Comment: @Luaan You're right, of course: we can `calculateTax()` in our country object and instead of having the caller perform `calculateTax(country, amount)` it just calls `country.calculateTax(amount)`. Much better. Will edit (if still possible).

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using `switch`: since JDK 12, `switch` expressions potentially improve readability and length of the `switch` statement by allowing multiple `case` labels and lambda-style syntax:

```java
private BigDecimal calculateTax(String country, BigDecimal amount) throws Exception {
    double rate = switch(country) {
        case "POLAND", "IRELAND" -> 0.23;
        case "AUSTRIA", "FRANCE" -> 0.20;
        case "CYPRUS", "GERMANY" -> 0.19;
        default -> throw new Exception("Country not supported");
    };
    return new BigDecimal(rate).multiply(amount);
}
```