# Improving if else with enum coding

Tags: java

I have a method that goes though Lectors (basically users) in a department and returns a JSON of integers of how many lectors are assigned to which degree (degree is an enum)

I have the method here:

```
    @Override
    public String getDepartmentStatistics(String departmentName) {
        List<Lector> lectorList = departmentRepository.getByName(departmentName).getLector();
        int assistantNumbers = 0;
        int associate_professorNumbers = 0;
        int professorNumbers = 0;
        for (Lector lector : lectorList) {
            if (lector.getLectorDegree().equals(ASSISTANT)) {
                assistantNumbers += 1;
            } else if (lector.getLectorDegree().equals(ASSOCIATE_PROFESSOR)) {
                associate_professorNumbers += 1;
            } else if (lector.getLectorDegree().equals(PROFESSOR)) {
                professorNumbers += 1;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(new JSONObject()
                .put("Assistants", assistantNumbers)
                .put("Associate professors", associate_professorNumbers)
                .put("Professors", professorNumbers));
    }
```

It's working as expected.

My question is how do i improve the quality/look of it?

Comment: Questions about improving the style of existing code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can use `switch`.

Comment: Why are you returning `null` if the degree is not one of your options?

Comment: Minor point: the JVM guarantees that enum elements are singleton objects, which means you can safely compare them using `==`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I improve readability and length of a method with many if statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586432/how-can-i-improve-readability-and-length-of-a-method-with-many-if-statements)

Comment: Returning `null` if you find another type of `Lector` is... unexpected. Better either to do nothing, or to throw some sort of exception to indicate an unhandled situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that uses a `Map` to keep track of all the counts:

```
enum Degree {
    PROFESSOR,
    ASSISTANT,
    ASSOCIATE_PROFESSOR
}

class Lector {
    Degree degree;

    public Degree getDegree() {
        return degree;
    }
}

public String getDepartmentStatistics(String departmentName) {
    List<Lector> lectorList = /*...*/
    Map<Degree, Integer> result = new EnumMap<>(Degree.class);

    lectorList.stream()
            .map(Lector::getDegree)
            .forEach(degree -> {
                Integer currentCount = result.getOrDefault(degree, 0);
                result.put(degree, ++currentCount);
            });

    return String.valueOf(new JSONObject()
            .put("Assistants", result.getOrDefault(Degree.ASSISTANT, 0))
            .put("Associate professors", result.getOrDefault(Degree.ASSOCIATE_PROFESSOR, 0))
            .put("Professors", result.getOrDefault(Degree.PROFESSOR, 0)));
}
```

Instead of `Stream.forEach` you can also group via the stream. You can also use `Map.compute` instead of `getOrDefault`. This version is my subjectively preferred solution as its pretty clear about what is happening.

Compared to using `if` or `switch` new `Degree` values work out of the box (only the return statement isn't generic yet, but it can be generified too).

EDIT: Improved solution with `Map.merge` as pointed out by Andy Turner:

```
public String getDepartmentStatistics(String departmentName) {
    List<Lector> lectorList = /*...*/
    Map<Degree, Integer> result = new EnumMap<>(Degree.class);

    lectorList.stream()
            .map(Lector::getDegree)
            .forEach(degree -> result.merge(degree, 1, Integer::sum));

    return String.valueOf(new JSONObject()
        .put("Assistants", result.getOrDefault(Degree.ASSISTANT, 0))
        .put("Associate professors", result.getOrDefault(Degree.ASSOCIATE_PROFESSOR, 0))
        .put("Professors", result.getOrDefault(Degree.PROFESSOR, 0)));
}
```

EDIT2:
Let me include a fully functional approach that does not mix imperative and functional approaches as much (as discussed in the comments):

```
public String getDepartmentStatistics(String departmentName) {
    List<Lector> lectorList = /*...*/
    Map<Degree, Integer> result =
        lectorList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                 Lector::getDegree,
                 () -> new EnumMap<>(Degree.class),
                 Collectors.counting()
            ));

    return String.valueOf(new JSONObject()
            .put("Assistants", result.getOrDefault(Degree.ASSISTANT, 0))
            .put("Associate professors", result.getOrDefault(Degree.ASSOCIATE_PROFESSOR, 0))
            .put("Professors", result.getOrDefault(Degree.PROFESSOR, 0)));
}
```

Comment: `lectorList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Lector::getDegree, counting()))` is preferable to `forEach`.

Comment: I dislike `groupingBy` here as it uses a `HashMap` by default and the overload for supplying another Map implementation is making the code bloated. But yeah, personal preference :) But the `counting()` is nice as you don't have to implement it on your own

Comment: `groupingBy(Lector::getDegree, () -> new EnumMap<>(Degree.class), counting())`. This is substantially less bloated than the code in your answer.

Comment: (Also, `result.merge(degree, 1, Integer::sum);` would be a neater way to do the `forEach` consumer).

Comment: As I told you: I consider the overload to be bloated here. A lot is going on in that line, but yeah its a good solution.

Oh I didn't know about merge- thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Absolutely brilliant solution

Comment: If you've got a copy of *Effective Java 3rd Ed* to hand, I recommend you check out the example half-way down the first page of item 46: it's almost exactly the same as this code, and Bloch is not exactly complimentary about it. It would be better to use the stream API correctly, or just use a plain loop.

Comment: I added a purely functional approach for completeness sake, thanks. Let's hope that Bloch doesn't find me

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `switch` statement to check the degree rather than multiple `if`s:

```
@Override
public String getDepartmentStatistics(String departmentName) {
    List<Lector> lectorList = departmentRepository.getByName(departmentName).getLector();
    int assistantNumbers = 0;
    int associate_professorNumbers = 0;
    int professorNumbers = 0;

    for (Lector lector : lectorList) {
        switch(lector.getLectorDegree()) {
            case ASSISTANT:
                assistantNumbers += 1;
                break;

            case ASSOCIATE_PROFESSOR:
                associate_professorNumbers += 1;
                break;

            case ASSISTANT:
                professorNumbers += 1;
                break;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    return String.valueOf(new JSONObject()
            .put("Assistants", assistantNumbers)
            .put("Associate professors", associate_professorNumbers)
            .put("Professors", professorNumbers));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing the if (or switch) statement with a list of strategies or visitors
(I'm not sure which name applies in this case).

Here is some example code (caveat: I did not try to compile this code):

```
public enum LectorDegreeType
{
  ASSISTANT("Assistants"),
  ASSOCIATE_PROFESSOR("Associate Professors"),
  PROFESSOR("Professor");

  private final title;

  LectorDegreeType(final String titleValue)
  {
    title = titleValue;
  }

  public String getTitle()
  {
    return title;
  }
}

public interface LectorBlammy
{
  void blam(@NotNull Lector lector);
  void retrieveTitle();
  void retrieveTotal();
}

public abstract class AbstractLectorBlammy
implements LectorBlammy
{
  private final LectorDegreeType desiredDegree;
  private int matchCount;

  protected AbstractLectorBlammy(
  @NotNull final LectorDegreeType desiredDegreeValue)
  {
    desiredDegree = Objects.requireNotNull(desiredDegreeValue);

    matchCount = 0;
  }

  // perhaps make this a final method.
  public void blam(@NotNull final Lector lector)
  {
    if (lector.getLectorDegree().equals(desiredDegree))
    {
      ++matchCount;
    }
  }

  public void retrieveTitle()
  {
    return desiredDegree.getTitle();
  }

  public void retrieveTotal()
  {
    return matchCount;
  }
}

public class LectorBlammyAssistant
extends AbstractLectorBlammy
{
  public LectorBlammyAssistant()
  {
    AbstractLectorBlammy(LectorDegreeType.ASSISTANT);
  }
}

public class LectorBlammyAssociateProfessor
extends AbstractLectorBlammy
{
  public LectorBlammyAssistant()
  {
    AbstractLectorBlammy(LectorDegreeType.ASSOCIATE_PROFESSOR);
  }
}

public class LectorBlammyProfessor
extends AbstractLectorBlammy
{
  public LectorBlammyAssistant()
  {
    AbstractLectorBlammy(LectorDegreeType.PROFESSOR);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but using a visitor seems to be such an overengineered solution here. Just look at the amount of classes you had to add. Nice to have another alternative though

Comment: The visitor interface in my example can easily be changed to a functional interface (the count method).  Also, the visitor allows the addition of more Lector types without change to the code that is counting the Lector types.

Comment: Yeah I definitively would not categorize this as improving the quality/look of the code